# Pandas dataframe divide rows based on dates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have one column of values on a daily level, and another column of values on a weekly level. I want to divide the daily values by the weekly value for the week in which the day falls, for the corresponding company and group.  I'm trying to figure out a way to do without a loop, and I feel like there is a way to do this in pandas or numpy, but I can't figure it out.  Thanks for the help!

For example, I have two data frames:

df1 =

```
Company Group Date       People
A       X     01/07/2015 5
A       X     01/14/2015 10
A       XX    01/07/2015 6
A       XX    01/14/2015 12
B       Y     01/07/2015 4
B       Y     01/14/2015 8
B       YY    01/07/2015 5
B       YY    01/14/2015 4
```

df2 =

```
Company Group Date       Value
A       X     01/04/2015 5
A       X     01/06/2015 10
A       X     01/13/2015 15
A       XX    01/05/2015 6
A       XX    01/06/2015 9
A       XX    01/11/2015 9
A       XX    01/14/2015 12
B       Y     01/05/2015 4
B       Y     01/07/2015 6
B       Y     01/13/2015 16
B       Y     01/14/2015 24
B       YY    01/03/2015 10
B       YY    01/11/2015 10
B       YY    01/14/2015 12
```

And I would like the result to be:

```
Company Group Date       Value/People
A       X     01/04/2015 1
A       X     01/06/2015 2
A       X     01/13/2015 1.5
A       XX    01/05/2015 1
A       XX    01/06/2015 1.5
A       XX    01/11/2015 0.75
A       XX    01/14/2015 1
B       Y     01/05/2015 1
B       Y     01/07/2015 1.5
B       Y     01/13/2015 2
B       Y     01/14/2015 3
B       YY    01/03/2015 2
B       YY    01/11/2015 2.5
B       YY    01/14/2015 3
```

Comment: your dates are not unique, so when you want to divide by the value for the week in which the day falls... which value do you choose?  This data is not sufficient.  Show us the loop you've tried.

Comment: I want to choose the value based on the corresponding Company and Group.  For example, for the first row in df2 (Company A and Group X), I want to divide the value by the row in df1 that corresponds to Company A, Group X, where the date in df2 (01/04/2015) falls into the week in df1 (01/07/2015).  I have amended my question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying dtype for date-like values stored in DataFrames and Series is NumPy [`datetime64[ns]`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html). Arrays of `datetime64[ns]` values can be "cropped" to a canonical second, minute, hour, day, week, month, or year by calling `astype('datetime64[?]')`, where `?` is replaced by the appropriate unit (e.g. `s`, `m`, `h`, `D`, `W`, `M`, `Y`).

Here, our problem would largely be solved if we could classify each date to a canonical week. We can do this using `.astype('datetime64[W]')`:

```
In [152]: df1['Week'] = df1['Date'].values.astype('datetime64[W]'); df1
Out[152]: 
  Company       Date Group  People       Week
0       A 2015-01-07     X       5 2015-01-01
1       A 2015-01-14     X      10 2015-01-08
2       A 2015-01-07    XX       6 2015-01-01
3       A 2015-01-14    XX      12 2015-01-08
4       B 2015-01-07     Y       4 2015-01-01
5       B 2015-01-14     Y       8 2015-01-08
6       B 2015-01-07    YY       5 2015-01-01
7       B 2015-01-14    YY       4 2015-01-08
```

Having done this for both `df1` and `df2`, we can now merge the DataFrames on `['Week', 'Group', 'Company']`. This will match the appropriate rows from df1 and df2. Finding the ratio of Value to People is then easy.

---

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'Date': ['01/07/2015', '01/14/2015', '01/07/2015', '01/14/2015', '01/07/2015', '01/14/2015', '01/07/2015', '01/14/2015'], 'Group': ['X', 'X', 'XX', 'XX', 'Y', 'Y', 'YY', 'YY'], 'People': [5, 10, 6, 12, 4, 8, 5, 4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'Date': ['01/04/2015', '01/06/2015', '01/13/2015', '01/05/2015', '01/06/2015', '01/11/2015', '01/14/2015', '01/05/2015', '01/07/2015', '01/13/2015', '01/14/2015', '01/03/2015', '01/11/2015', '01/14/2015'], 'Group': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'XX', 'XX', 'XX', 'XX', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'YY', 'YY', 'YY'], 'Value': [5, 10, 15, 6, 9, 9, 12, 4, 6, 16, 24, 10, 10, 12]})

for df in [df1, df2]:
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    df['Week'] = df['Date'].values.astype('datetime64[W]')

result = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='left', on=['Week', 'Group', 'Company'], suffixes=['', '_1'])
result['Value/People'] = result['Value']/result['People']
result = result[['Company', 'Group', 'Date', 'Value/People']]
print(result)
```

yields

```
   Company Group       Date  Value/People
0        A     X 2015-01-04          1.00
1        A     X 2015-01-06          2.00
2        A     X 2015-01-13          1.50
3        A    XX 2015-01-05          1.00
4        A    XX 2015-01-06          1.50
5        A    XX 2015-01-11          0.75
6        A    XX 2015-01-14          1.00
7        B     Y 2015-01-05          1.00
8        B     Y 2015-01-07          1.50
9        B     Y 2015-01-13          2.00
10       B     Y 2015-01-14          3.00
11       B    YY 2015-01-03          2.00
12       B    YY 2015-01-11          2.50
13       B    YY 2015-01-14          3.00
```

---

Note that there is "base offset" issue that needs to be considered when cropping dates to a canonical week. In other words, you need to decide when does a week begin. If you do not like the canonical choice being made by `df['Date'].values.astype('datetime64[W]')`, you may need to add an offset to the dates. For example, to add a day to the dates in `df['Date']` you could use:

```
(df['Date'].values + np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype('datetime64[W]')
```